# Apply my hash to a string to get numbers from letters

Tags: perl, hash

I am trying to convert letters to their respective number in the alphabet. I have a hash that I think should work I just dont know how to apply it to my string.

string:

```
my $string = "abc";
```

and my hash:

```
@hash{("a".."z")} = (1..26);
```

how do i get my string to be 123 in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "abc";
my %hash;
@hash{("a".."z")} = (1..26); 
$string =~ s/(.)/$hash{$1}/g;
print "$string\n";

__END__

123
```

UPDATE: Another way, without a hash, is to use [ord](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html)

```
my $string = "abc";
$string =~ s/(.)/ord($1) - 96/ge;
print "$string\n";
```

Comment: Note: neither handle inputs with characters outside of a..z. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

General solution:

```
my %lookup; @lookup{"a".."z"} = 1..26;
my $pat = '(?:'.( join '|', map quotemeta, keys %lookup ).')';

s/($pat)/$lookup{$1}/g;
```

Assumes keys consist of at most one character:

```
my %lookup; @lookup{"a".."z"} = 1..26;
my $class = '['.( join '', map quotemeta, keys %lookup ).']';

s/($class)/$lookup{$1}/g;
```

"Hardcoded":

```
$string =~ s/([a-z])/ ord($1) - ord('a') + 1 /ge;
```